# in powershell how to access current object properties

Tags: powershell, azure

the first and second `$_.Name` is for the container. Of this for each of the container i want to filter out the name of the files in a container so in the `Where-Object` i use `$_.Name` which i assume would be name of the file but `$_.` keeps referring to container's name and not the filename. How do filter out by file name.

```
$containers = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $ctx

    $containers|ForEach-Object{

    Write-Host 'Container: ' $_.Name

    $fileName = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $ctx -Container $_.Name|Where-Object {$_.Name -contains '.vhd'}    

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to avoid using a syntax like `$containers | ForEach-Object` if you need to perform multiple actions inside the cycle.

Try insead using `foreach ($container in $containers)`, so your code will be something like

```
foreach ($container in $containers) {
    Write-Host 'Container: ' $container.Name
    $fileName = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $ctx -Container $container.Name | Where-Object {$_.Name -contains '.vhd'}
}
```